# Delete all the data of BBPress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, bbpress

I would like to delete all the data related to bbPress Wordpress, some how millions of records are inserted into my blog and i will use this query to delete the records

```
DELETE from wp_btei_postmeta 
where 
Post_id IN (select distinct ID from wp_btei_posts where post_type in ('forum', 'topic', 'reply'))
```

I want to know is this the right thing I am doing ? Will it delete other data than my forum ? because i read on BBPress that they use the above three types of post and uses the main post table only.

Comment: No above query will only delete the meta data of selected posts it will not delete posts

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid yes you are right and i will delete from POST also , but m asking if this clause is fine ?

Comment: If you have millions of row then a subquery will surely be an expensive solution instead if tables are indexed properly then use a join query in delete which  will surely save some time

Comment: http://codex.buddypress.org/getting-started/deleting-buddypress/

Answer (score 2):

bbPress includes a tool to delete all the bbPress data

- Install and activate the bbPress plugin again
- Go to Tools -> Forums -> "Reset Forums" tab
- Check the "Are you sure you want to do this?" checkbox
- Click "Reset bbPress"
- Deactivate and delete the bbPress plugin

This will remove all bbPress data from your WordPress database, including custom post types, topic tag taxonomy and user meta.

Comment: I was not able to login to my web portal , as because of the bulk spam my blog and database has stuck. That is the reason i am querying the table directly.